# How is co-recursion handled?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Ok basically I have a problem knowing whether option 1 or 2 applies in the following case:

```
naturals = 0 : map (+ 1) naturals
```

Where options are:
1. The execution is awful, everything is recomputed at each step:

```
naturals     = [0]
naturals'    = 0:map (+ 1) [0]          // == [0, 1]
naturals''   = 0:map (+ 1) [0, 1]       // == [0, 1, 2]
naturals'''  = 0:map (+ 1) [0, 1, 2]    // == [0, 1, 2, 3]
naturals'''' = 0:map (+ 1) [0, 1, 2, 3] // == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

2. The execution is not awful, the list is always infinite and `map` is applied once only

```
naturals     = 0:something
                                  |
naturals'    = 0:      map (+ 1) (0:      something)
                                    |
naturals''   = 0:1:    map (+ 1) (0:1:    something')
                                      |
naturals'''  = 0:1:2:  map (+ 1) (0:1:2:  something'')
                                        |
naturals'''' = 0:1:2:3:map (+ 1) (0:1:2:3:something''')
```

with `|` indicating where `map` is at in its execution.

I do know that answers may be only *1* or *2* but I'd appreciate some pointers to good explanations on co-recursion too to clear the last doubts :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Execution isn't going to be, as you put it, "awful". :) Lazy evaluation is your best friend here. What does laziness mean?

1. Things are not evaluated before their results are really needed;
2. Things are evaluated at most once.

"Things", here, are "not-yet-evaluated expressions", also known as "thunks".

Here is what happens:

You define

```
naturals = 0 : map (+1) naturals
```

Merely defining `naturals` doesn't introduce a need to evaluate it, so initially `naturals` will just point to a thunk for the unevaluated expression `0 : map (+1) naturals`:

```
naturals = <thunk0>
```

At some point, your program may pattern match on naturals. (Pattern matching is essentially the only thing that forces evaluation in a Haskell program.) That is, your program needs to know whether naturals is the empty list or a head element followed by a tail list. This is where the right-hand side of your definition will be evaluated, but only as far as needed to find out whether `naturals` is constructed by `[]` or `(:)`:

```
naturals = 0 : <thunk1>
```

That is naturals will now point to an application of the constructor `(:)` on the head element `0` and a thunk for the still-unevaluated tail. (Actually, the head element will also be still-unevaluated, so really `naturals` will point to something of the form `<thunk> : <thunk>`, but I will be leaving that detail out.)

It is not until some later point in your program where you may pattern match on the tail that the thunk for the tail gets "forced", i.e., evaluated. This means that the expression `map (+1) naturals` is to be evaluated. Evaluating this expression reduces to `map` pattern matching on `naturals`: it needs to know whether `naturals` is constructed by `[]` or `(:)`.
We saw that, at this point, rather than pointing to a thunk, `naturals` is already pointing to an application of `(:)`, so this pattern match by `map` requires no further evaluation. The application of `map` does immediately see enough of `naturals` to figure out that it needs to produce an application of `(:)` itself and so it does: `map` produces `1 : <thunk2>` where the thunk contains an unevaluated expression of the form `map (+1) <?>`. (Again, instead of `1`, we actually have a thunk for `0 + 1`.) What is `<?>` pointing to? Well, the tail of `naturals`, which happens to be what `map` was producing. Hence, we now have

```
naturals = 0 : 1 : <thunk2>
```

with `<thunk2>` containing the yet-unevaluated expression `map (+1) (1 : <thunk2>)`.

At yet a later point in your program, pattern matching may force `<thunk2>`, so that we get

```
naturals = 0 : 1 : 2 : <thunk3>
```

with `<thunk3>` containing the yet-unevaluated expression `map (+1) (2 : <thunk3>)`. And so forth.

Comment: So each element will be an ever-greater thunk made up of a bunch of additions?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Yes, unless of course the program forces the evaluation of the elements. This is what makes the space complexity of lazily evaluated programs sometimes hard to reason about: even experiences Haskell programmers sometimes get surprised by the memory requirements of innocently looking programs. And this is why we have `seq` and the like.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to figure this out but if you want to find (say) the billionth natural number,

```
n = nats !! 1000000000
```

you hit a thunk buildup in the 1+ operation.  I ended up rewriting (!!):

```
nth (x:xs) n = if n==0 then x else x `seq` nth xs (n-1)
```

I tried several ways to rewrite the definition of nats to force each element, instead of writing nth, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: If you want to do it from `naturals`, you have to tie the evaluation of each element to the corresponding `(:)` constructor, which you can't do with `map`. However, you can do it with `foldr`, e.g. ```nats = 0 : foldr f [] nats where f x ys = let y = x+1 in y `seq` (y : ys)```

Comment: stepping over bigger chunks might be faster: ``nnth xs k n | k>n = head xs`seq`(xs!!n) | otherwise = head xs`seq`(case drop k xs of [] -> xs!!n ; ys -> nnth ys k (n-k))``. a related code in the context of arrays is http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238950/849891 .

Answer (score 1):

```
map f xs = f (head xs) : map f (tail xs)
p0 = 0 : map (+ 1) p0

-- when p0 is pattern-matched against:
p0 = "0" :Cons: "map (+ 1) {p0}"    
-- when (tail p0) is pattern-matched against:
-- {tail p0} := p1,
p1 = "(+ 1) (head {p0})" :Cons: "map (+ 1) (tail {p0})"       
-- when (tail p1) is pattern-matched against:
-- {tail p1} := p2,
p2 = "(+ 1) (head {p1})" :Cons: "map (+ 1) (tail {p1})"
```

Haskell's lists are a lot like Prolog's open-ended lists, and co-recursion on lists is like tail recursion modulo cons. Once you instantiate that logvar - set a list's cell value from some expression -  it just holds that value ready, there's no more reference to the originating context.

```
naturals( [A|T] ):- T=[B|R], B=A+1, naturals( T ). % "=" sic! ("thunk build-up")
```

To overcome Prolog's strictness we make *future access* drive the process:

```
naturals( nats(0) ).
next( nats(A), A, nats(B) ):- 
  B is A+1.                    % fix the evaluation to be done immediately
take( 0, Next, Z-Z, Next).
take( N, Next, [A|B]-Z, NZ):- N>0, !, next(Next,A,Next1),
  N1 is N-1,                
  take(N1,Next1,B-Z,NZ).
```

Haskell has this taken care of effortlessly, its "storage" is naturally lazy (i.e. the list constructor is lazy, and list construction is only "awoken" by access, by the very nature of the language).

### Fix

Compare these:

```
fix f = f (fix f)         
fix f = x where x = f x   -- "co-recursive" fix ?
```

Now see your original concern become real when the first definition is used in the following:

```
g = fix $ (0:) . scanl (+) 1
```

Its empirical complexity is actually quadratic, or worse. But with the second definition it's linear, as it should be.

Comment: I forgot to say thanks but it's an interesting parallel. I didn't realize it was actually tail recursion modulo cons before you pointed it out :)

Comment: I think it is. It's also just like Python's generators.  I think. :)

Comment: ...and accumulator-argument technique too: `fac n = let { go a k | k==n = a; go a k = go (a*(k+1)) (k+1)} in go 1 0 = (!! n) $ scanl (*) 1 [1..] = (!! n) (let xs = zipWith (*) (1:xs) [1..] in (1:xs))` -- it's about "counting up" -- and recursion is about "counting down". I think. :)

Comment: also, of course, the difference lists, or the incomplete structures (with holes, etc.).