# Why is my intuition about self referential lazy sequences wrong?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In Haskell I can write a self referential sequence, in GHCI, like so:

```
λ> let x = 1:map (+1) x
λ> take 5 x
```

which produces:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

However my intuition on lazy evaluation says this should happen during expansion

```
let x = 1:map (+1) x
1:2:map (+1) x
1:2:map (+1) [1, 2] <-- substitution
1:2:2:3:map (+1) x
1:2:2:3:map (+1) [1, 2, 2, 3] <-- substitution
1:2:2:3:2:3:3:4:map (+1) x
...
```

This is obviously not what's happening.  I can see the pattern in the correct answer.  We are merely moving one element in the list at a time down an infinite stream.  The pattern I recognize and I can apply it in code.  However it does not line up with my mental model of lazy evaluation.  It feels a bit "magic".  Where is my intuition wrong?

Comment: Forgot an `in` in your first example?

Comment: @Jefffrey That's valid syntax for a ghci session

Comment: You treat `x` as if it has a different value based on how much has been evaluated. This is not the case. `x` *always* has the value `[1,2,3...]`. After all, it is a pure value and it cannot depend on time or the runtimes internal state. You can treat this as textual substitution: `x = 1:map (+1) x => x = 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) x) => 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) x))`, etc.

Comment: also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257326

Comment: @user2407038 that's not taking memoization of thunks into account.

Comment: http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Fix_and_recursion explains a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remember only to substitute something with its definition.  So whenever you expand `x`, you should substitute `1 : map (+1) x`, not its "current value" (whatever that means).

I'll reproduce Jefffrey's idea, but with due respect for laziness.

```
x = 1 : map (+1) x

take 5 x
= take 5 (1 : map (+1) x)                                 -- x
= 1 : take 4 (map (+1) x)                                 -- take
= 1 : take 4 (map (+1) (1 : map (+1) x)                   -- x
= 1 : take 4 (2 : map (+1) (map (+1) x))                  -- map and (+)
= 1 : 2 : take 3 (map (+1) (map (+1) x))                  -- take
= 1 : 2 : take 3 (map (+1) (map (+1) (1 : map (+1) x)))   -- x
= 1 : 2 : take 3 (map (+1) (2 : map (+1) (map (+1) x)))   -- map and (+)
= 1 : 2 : take 3 (3 : map (+1) (map (+1) (map (+1) x)))   -- map and (+)
= 1 : 2 : 3 : take 2 (map (+1) (map (+1) (map (+1) x)))   -- take
```

and so on.

**Exercise** finish the evaluation in this style yourself (it's quite informative).

Notice how we are starting to build up a chain of `map`s as the list grows.  If you just `print x`, you will see the output start to slow down after a while; this is why.  There is a more efficient way, left as an exercise (and `[1..]` is cheating :-).

N.B. this is *still* a little less lazy than what will actually happen.  `map (+1) (1 : ...)` evaluates to `(1+1) : map (+1) ...`, and the addition will only happen when the number is actually observed, by either printing it or e.g. comparing it.

*Will Ness identified an error in this post; see the comments and his answer.*

Comment: your reduction sequence doesn't take memoization into account. laziness = non-strict reduction (what you show) + *memoization*. i.e. you show the reduction for the definition `x = _Y ( (1:) . map (1+)) where _Y g = g (_Y g)` which eliminates sharing; but the actual definition is `x = fix ( (1:).map(1+)) where { fix f = x where x = f x}`. -- Consider this: in your resulting sequence `1:2:3:4:...`, 2 is result of two invocations of (1+) and 3 - of three invocations of (1+), separate of those that produced 2. But with sharing, the increments that went into 2, are reused when producing 3.

Comment: correction, 3 is result of two (1+) invocations, and 4 is result of separate three (1+) invocations, clearly seen on the last line of your reduction sequence. Which is not what happens (hopefully) in GHC or any other sane implementation.

Comment: IOW this answer is incorrect. And `[1..]` is ***not*** cheating - it is exactly equivalent, because `succ == (1+)`. :)  Indeed, there's only a slowdown with `_Y ((1:).map(1+))`; with `fix ((1:).map(1+))` (or with the OP's definition) there's no slowdown.

Comment: @WillNess, I think you're right, thanks.  I'm trying to think of a good way to present the evaluation taking this into account.

Comment: I think naming the interim entities helps, as I do in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what happens. **Laziness is non-strictness + *memoization* (of thunks)**. We can show this by naming all the interim data that come into existence as the expression is forced:

```
λ> let x  = 1  : map (+1) x
   >>> x  = a1 : x1                             -- naming the subexpressions
       a1 = 1
       x1 = map (+1) x 

λ> take 5 x 
==> take 5 (a1:x1)                              -- definition of x
==> a1:take 4 x1                                -- definition of take
          >>> x1 = map (1+) (1:x1)              -- definition of x
                 = (1+) 1 : map (1+) x1         -- definition of map
                 = a2     : x2                  -- naming the subexpressions
              a2 = (1+) 1                        
              x2 = map (1+) x1  
==> a1:take 4 (a2:x2)                           -- definition of x1
==> a1:a2:take 3 x2                             -- definition of take
             >>> x2 = map (1+) (a2:x2)          -- definition of x1
                    = (1+) a2 : map (1+) x2     -- definition of map
                    = a3      : x3              -- naming the subexpressions
                 a3 = (1+) a2                    
                 x3 = map (1+) x2  
==> a1:a2:take 3 (a3:x3)                        -- definition of x2
==> a1:a2:a3:take 2 x3                          -- definition of take
                >>> x3 = map (1+) (a3:x3)       -- definition of x2
.....
```

The elements in the resulting stream `a1:a2:a3:a4:...` each refer to its predecessor: `a1 = 1; a2 = (1+) a1; a3 = (1+) a2; a4 = (1+) a3; ...`.

Thus it is equivalent to `x = iterate (1+) 1`. Without the sharing of data and its reuse through back-reference (enabled by the memoization of storage), it would be equivalent to `x = [sum $ replicate n 1 | n <- [1..]]` which is a radically less efficient computation (*O(n<sup>2</sup>)* instead of *O(n)*).

We can explicate the sharing vs non-sharing with

```
fix g = x where x = g x        -- sharing fixpoint
x = fix ((1:) . map (1+))      --  corecursive definition

_Y g = g (_Y g)                -- non-sharing fixpoint
y = _Y ((1:) . map (1+))       --  recursive definition
```

Trying to print out `y` at GHCi's prompt shows a marked slowdown as the progression goes along. There's no slowdown when printing out the `x` stream.

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978114/849891 for a similar example).

Comment: This should be accepted answer and it did reveal the truth of lazy evaluation. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You're mapping `+1` over the entire list, so that initial `1` becomes `n`, where `n` is the number of times you have lazily recursed, if that makes sense. So instead of the derivation that you're thinking of, it looks more like this:

```
1:...                            -- [1 ...]
1: map (+1) (1:...)              -- [1, 2 ...]
1: map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:...)) -- [1, 2, 3 ...]
```

A `1` gets prepended to a lazily computed list whose elements all get incremented during each step of recursion.

So you can sort of think of the `n`th step of recursion as taking the list `[1, 2, 3, ..., n ...]`, turning it into the list `[2, 3, 4, ..., n+1 ...]`, and prepending a `1`.

Comment: "and prepending a `1`" this is actually a reverse of what happens. lists (as any lazy data) are fleshed out from the top down, by access. This is the foundation of [efficiency of corecursive definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion#Factorial), translated into iterative computations (not unlike [the TRMC optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons)).

Comment: @WillNess Makes sense -- thanks! I still think it's instructive to think of it in this way (though perhaps my sentence about prepending initially was incorrect), but I can see the difference.

Comment: you meant it semantically, as a way to understand/explain the definition. :)

Comment: May I suggest that you replace, e.g., the comment `"[1, 2]"` with the comment `[1, 2, ...]` or `[1, 2, ???]` or even just `[1, 2, ...`? These are not completed lists and shouldn't be represented so.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this a bit more mathematically. Suppose that

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

Then

```
map (+1) x = [2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

so

```
1 : map (+1) x = 1 : [2, 3, 4, 5, ...] = x
```

This (turned around) is the equation we started with:

```
x = 1 : map (+1) x
```

So what we've shown is that

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

is a solution of the equation

```
x = 1 : map (+1) x   -- Eqn 1
```

The next question, of course, is whether there are any *other* solutions to Eqn 1. The answer, as it turns out, is no. This is important because Haskell's evaluation model effectively chooses the "least-defined" solution of any such equation. For example, if we instead defined `x = 1 : tail x`, then *any* list starting with `1` would be a solution, but we would *actually* get `1 : _|_`, where `_|_` represents an error or non-termination. Eqn 1 does not lead to this sort of mess:

Let `y` be any solution of Eqn 1, so

```
y = 1 : map (+1) y
```

Note that we can tell from the definition that

```
take 1 y = [1] = take 1 x
```

Now suppose

```
take n y = take n x
```

Then

```
take (n+1) y = take (n+1) (1 : map (+1) y)
             = 1 : take n (map (+1) y)
             = 1 : map (+1) (take n y)
             = 1 : map (+1) (take n x)
             = 1 : take n (map (+1) x)
             = take (n+1) (1 : map (+1) x)
             = take (n+1) x
```

By induction, we find that `take n y = take n x` for each `n`. That is, `y = x`.

Answer (score 0):

#### What you have got wrong

In your order of evaluation:

```
let x = 1:map (+1) x
1:2:map (+1) x
1:2:map (+1) [1, 2] <-- here
```

you are making a wrong assumption. You are assuming `x` is `[1, 2]` because that's the number of elements you can see there. It's not. You have forgot to consider that the `x` at the end needs to be calculated recursively.

#### The actual flow

The `x` at the end of the sequence needs to be computed by recursively computing itself. Here's the actual flow:

```
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) [1 ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) [1, 2 ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) (1:map (+1) [1, 2, 3 ...
take 5 $ 1:map (+1) [1, 2, 3, 4 ...
take 5 $ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Helpful expansion, though it's misleading to call this the "order of evaluation".  This doesn't correspond to the order in which things will actually be calculated.

Comment: you are forcing the whole tail before prepending; this won't work on infinite lists (while in ghci you can see that it does). See my answer.

Comment: laziness means thunks are memoized; check out my answer, where I show it by naming the interim entities.

Comment: The error is one line *before* what you've marked. `1 : map (+1) x` does *not* expand to `1 : 2 : map (+1) x`. Rather, it expands, essentially, to `1 : map (+1) (1 : tail x)`, which expands to `1 : 2 : map (+1) (tail x)`, which expands to `1 : 2 : map (+1) (2 : tail (tail x))`, etc.

Comment: @WillNess, right. I was only explaining it from a correctness perspective, not an efficiency perspective.